# How to tell if a character is an ASCII uppercase letter in Clojure

Tags: clojure, ascii

I got a seq like this:

```
(\$ \# \A \( \* \& \9 \8 \7 \Z \f)
```

I want to filter out uppercase ASCII letters in it like \A and \Z

I tried to look up in the standard library but no luck.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the following

```
(filter #(Character/isUpperCase %) `(\$ \# \A \( \* \& \9 \8 \7 \Z \f))
```

Results : `(\A \Z)`

Comment: Thanks. It is a java function haha.

Comment: Without using Java: `(filter #(not= (str %) (clojure.string/lower-case %)) \`(\$ \# \A \( \* \& \9 \8 \7 \Z \f))`

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
(filter (set (map char (range 65 91))) 
       '(\$ \# \A \( \* \& \9 \8 \7 \Z \f))
```

Returns:

```
'(\A \Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you might also use `re-seq` and regular expressions:

`((fn [x]
    (seq (apply str (re-seq #"[A-Z]" (apply str x)))))
 '(\$ \# \A \( \* \& \9 \8 \7 \Z \f))`

which also returns `(\A \Z)`.

Comment: Assuming `x` is already a string, the innermost `(apply str x)` can be replaced with just `x`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more verbose, but you can also define your own function to do it:

```
(defn cap-detector [x]
     (loop [res []
            arg (apply str x)]
        (cond (empty? arg) (filter (fn [x] (Character/isLetter x)) res)
              :else (if (= (clojure.string/upper-case (first arg)) (str (first arg)))
                    (recur (conj res (first arg)) (rest arg))
                    (recur res (rest arg))))))
```

And call the `cap-detector` with your sequence of characters will give you what you want:

```
(cap-detector '(\$ \# \A \( \* \& \9 \8 \7 \Z \f))
; => (\A \Z)
```